# What should be proved in the binomial theorem?

Tags: proof-writing, binomial-coefficients

I'm following Cambrige mathematics syllabus, from the list of contents of what should be learned:

> Induction as a method of proof, including a proof of the binomial theorem with non-negative integral coefficients.

I know what it is, but I'm not sure of what should be proved here. The first thing that comes to mind is the idea of proving it it for $n+1$, but I thought about writing:

- $(a+b)^n$
- $(a+b)^{n+1}$

But I am missing what premise I should prove. I guess that the proof involves the nature of the coefficients of the expansion of $(a+b)^n$ but from here, I have no idea on how to proceed.
Can you help me?

---

**Edit**: I guess I've made some progress. First I evaluated

$$(x+y)^0=1$$

Then I've evaluated it with the summation form

$$\sum_{j=0}^{0}{n \choose j}x^{n-j}y^{j}$$

And confirmed that it's equal to $1$ (I guess this is the base step).

The I did the same for $n+1$:

$$(x+y)^1=x+y$$

Then I've evaluated again for the summation form and checked that the results are the same. Is this all that should be done?

Comment: The binomial theorem is a sequence $P(n)$ of statements $(a + b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} a^k b^{n-k}$. Proving the binomial theorem by induction means proving $P(1)$ (or, if you want to be really cool, $P(0)$) and proving that $P(n)$ implies $P(n+1)$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan *Be really cool* means that it's in a godlike level of impossibility?

Comment: No, it just means that you're comfortable figuring out what the binomial theorem for $n = 0$ means. I don't claim that this is particularly hard but some people might be scared of it.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan What's the meaning of $ {n \choose k} a^k b^{n-k}$? Is it the product $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \times a^k b^{n-k}$?

Comment: Yes. What else would it mean?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Don't know, maybe it was a reference to some unknown obscure mathematical concept. I am making such questions since I discovered that $0!=1$ - It was a complete surprise.

Comment: Why would I reference an unknown obscure mathematical concept in the statement of the binomial theorem?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Perhaps you could presume something that you think is obvious for you but not for me. Something like that.

Comment: The inductive proof of the binomial theorem isn't difficult, but it might be a better idea to start with some easier examples of induction.

Comment: You have already accepted an answer on Jun 9; what does it mean for you to edit the question and ask something again? :-) Does it mean your question is not fully answered yet? Anyway the answer to the latest line in the question ("Is this all that should be done?") is no, this is not all that should be done. You have verified it for $n = 0$ and $n = 1$, but what you need to prove is that if (*whenever*) it's true for some $n = k$, then it's also true for $n = k +1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the expansion of $(a+b)^n$, it follows that the expansion of $(a+b)^{n+1}=(a+b)(a+b)^n=a(a+b)^n+b(a+b)^n$ can be found by distributing term by term and collecting coefficients. This is the type of reasoning you should use when doing inductive proofs.